# getting start and end time in java

Tags: java, time

i want to get the value of startTime and endTime from java gui to database.

ComputerSeats class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SeatMonitoringDesign extends JFrame 
{
public JLabel LStation, LID, LFirstName, LLastName, LTimeIn;
public JLabel[] Astation,Aid, Afirstname, Alastname, Atime;
public JRadioButton[] seat = new JRadioButton[10];
private String str = "";
private int station, occupiedSeatCounter;
private JLabel studNum, seatNum;
private ButtonGroup seatGroup = new ButtonGroup();
private boolean[] seatOccupied = new boolean[10];
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
private JTextField studNumTF;
private JButton logIn, logOut;
private ButtonHandler logInB;
private ButtonHandler logOutB;
private ButtonHandler radioB;


public SeatMonitoringDesign()
{

studNum = new JLabel("Enter Your Student Number: ");
studNum.setLocation(30,20);
studNum.setSize(200,100);

studNumTF = new JTextField(7);
studNumTF.setLocation(50,80);
studNumTF.setSize(120,30);

seatNum = new JLabel("Station Numbers: ");
seatNum.setLocation(60,90);
seatNum.setSize(600,400);

setTitle("Computer Seat Registration");

Container pane = getContentPane();

 pane.setLayout(null);
 pane.add(studNum);
 pane.add(studNumTF);

 setSize(1130,500);
 setResizable(false);
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

int x=50,y=150;
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
switch(i)
{
    case 0: str = "1"; break;
    case 1: str = "2"; break;
    case 2: str = "3"; break;
    case 3: str = "4"; break;
    case 4: str = "5"; break;
    case 5: str = "6"; break;
    case 6: str = "7"; break;
    case 7: str = "8"; break;
    case 8: str = "9"; break;
    case 9: str = "10"; break;
}
seat[i] = new JRadioButton(str);
seat[i].setSize(60,40);
seat[i].setLocation(x,y);
radioB = new ButtonHandler();
seat[i].addItemListener(radioB);
seat[i].setBackground(Color.green);
seatGroup.add(seat[i]);
pane.add(seat[i]);
x=110;

if((i+1)%2==0)
{
    x=50;
    y=y+30;
}
}

for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
seatOccupied[i] = false;
}

logIn = new JButton("Log In");
logIn.setSize(100,30);
logIn.setLocation(15,350);
logIn.setBackground(Color.orange);
logInB = new ButtonHandler();
logIn.addActionListener(logInB);
pane.add(logIn);

logOut = new JButton("Log Out");
logOut.setSize(100,30);
logOut.setLocation(125,350);
logOut.setBackground(Color.orange);
logOutB = new ButtonHandler();
logOut.addActionListener(logOutB);
pane.add(logOut);

LStation = new JLabel("Station #", SwingConstants.CENTER);
LStation.setSize(100,20);
LStation.setLocation(280,60);
pane.add(LStation);

LID = new JLabel("Student Number");
LID.setSize(100,20);
LID.setLocation(450,60);
pane.add(LID);

LFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
LFirstName.setSize(100,20);
LFirstName.setLocation(630,60);
pane.add(LFirstName);

LLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
LLastName.setSize(100,20);
LLastName.setLocation(810,60);
pane.add(LLastName);

LTimeIn = new JLabel("Time In");
LTimeIn.setSize(100,20);
LTimeIn.setLocation(990,60);
pane.add(LTimeIn);

Astation = new JLabel[10];
Aid = new JLabel[10];
Afirstname = new JLabel[10];
Alastname = new JLabel[10];
Atime = new JLabel[10];

y=85;
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{ 
switch(i)
{
    case 0: str = "1"; break;
    case 1: str = "2"; break;
    case 2: str = "3"; break;
    case 3: str = "4"; break;
    case 4: str = "5"; break;
    case 5: str = "6"; break;
    case 6: str = "7"; break;
    case 7: str = "8"; break;
    case 8: str = "9"; break;
    case 9: str = "10"; break;
}

Astation[i] = new JLabel(str, SwingConstants.CENTER);
Astation[i].setSize(100,30);
Astation[i].setLocation(280,y);
pane.add(Astation[i]);

Aid[i] = new JLabel("Vacant Station");
Aid[i].setSize(100,30);
Aid[i].setLocation(450,y);
pane.add(Aid[i]);

Afirstname[i] = new JLabel("---------");
Afirstname[i].setSize(100,30);
Afirstname[i].setLocation(630,y);
pane.add(Afirstname[i]);

Alastname[i] = new JLabel("---------");
Alastname[i].setSize(100,30);
Alastname[i].setLocation(810,y);
pane.add(Alastname[i]);

Atime[i] = new JLabel("00:00:00--");
Atime[i].setSize(100,30);
Atime[i].setLocation(990,y);
pane.add(Atime[i]);
y = y+30;
}
setVisible(true);

}

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
  for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == seat[i])
        station = (i+1);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
LogicalChecker lc = new LogicalChecker();
cobadatabase cb = new cobadatabase(studNumTF.getText());

String output;
Date now1 = new Date();
Date now2 = new Date();

//long secs = (now2.getTime() - now1.getTime()) / 1000;
//long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60; 
//long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60; 
// long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;

//long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//long elapsedTime = finishTime - startTime; 

long diff = (now2.getTime() - now1.getTime());
cobadatabase cb2 = new       cobadatabase(studNumTF.getText(),dateFormatter.format(now1),dateFormatter.format(now2),      diff);


if("Log In".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
{         
    if(station == 0)
    {
        lc.StationCheck(0);
    }
    else if(seatOccupied[station-1] == true)
    {
        lc.StationCheck(2);
    }
    else if(!studNumTF.getText().equals(cb.getStudentNumber()))
    {
         studNumTF.setText("");
         lc.StationCheck(3); 
    }
    else
    {

       seatOccupied[station-1] = true;

            Aid[station-1].setText(cb.getStudentNumber());
            Afirstname[station-1].setText(cb.getFirstName());
            Alastname[station-1].setText(cb.getLastName());  
            seat[station-1].setBackground(Color.red);
            Atime[station-1].setText(dateFormatter.format(now1));
            occupiedSeatCounter++;
    }
}

if("Log Out".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
 {


    if(station == 0)
    {
        lc.StationCheck(0);
    }
    else if(Aid[station-1].getText() == "Vacant Station")
    {
        lc.StationCheck(1);
    }
    else
    {

        Aid[station-1].setText("Vacant Station");
        Afirstname[station-1].setText("---------");
        Alastname[station-1].setText("---------");
        seat[station-1].setBackground(Color.green);
        Atime[station-1].setText("00:00:00");
        seatOccupied[station-1] = false;
        studNumTF.setText("");
        output = "Time Check-Out "+dateFormatter.format(now2)+"\n Total Time: "     +diff;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "Check-    Out.",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
}

}
} 

}
```

cobadatabase class

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class cobadatabase{
protected String sn,fn,ln,srt, sn2, srt2, et;
protected Long tt;
private Connection conn;
private PreparedStatement st; 

public cobadatabase(){
    try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       conn =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentrecords","root","");

        }

catch(Exception e){}
}

 public cobadatabase(String sn2, String str2, String et, long tt)
{
    this();
    try
    {
    st = conn.prepareStatement("Insert into time(StudentNumber,StartTime,EndTime,TotalTime) values(?,?,?,?)");
    st.setString(1,sn2);
    st.setString(2,str2);
    st.setString(3,et);
    st.setLong(4,tt);
    st.executeUpdate();

}
catch(Exception e){}
}

public cobadatabase(String StudentNumber)
{

    this();
    try{
       st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student WHERE StudentNumber=?");
       st.setString(1,StudentNumber);
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                this.sn = rs.getString(1);
                this.fn = rs.getString(2);
                this.ln = rs.getString(3);
                this.srt = rs.getString(4);

                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
                ft.format(rs.getTime("TotalTime").getTime());
            }   
}
catch(Exception e){}
}

public cobadatabase(String StudentNumber2, String Start, String End)
{

    this();
    try{
       st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM time WHERE StudentNumber2=?");
       st.setString(2,Start);
       st.setString(3,End);
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                this.sn2 = rs.getString(1);
                this.srt2 = rs.getString(2);
                this.et = rs.getString(3);
                this.tt = rs.getLong(4);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}



    public String getFirstName(){
    return fn;
}
    public String getLastName(){
    return ln;
}
    public String getStudentNumber(){
    return sn;
}
    public String getStart(){
    return srt2;
}
    public String getEnd(){
    return et;
}

}
```

the problem here is that when the login button is clicked, the start time displays both on the startTime and endTime column in my database. And when the log out button is clicked, another row is created in the database which contains the endTime on both startTime and endTime column.. I am wondering why does this happen..

Comment: I don't understand...you initialize `now1` and `now2` right after each other, so there's quite a large chance they'll represent the exact same date/time (since they are only precise to milliseconds). Shouldn't you be initializing the latter **after** you've done the operation you want to measure?

Comment: When you need to measure time in Java applications, you use `System.nanotime()`, it is more accurate than using `Date` differences.

Comment: @Abu, any specific reason why the former is not preferred? I thought that is more foolproof way to counter NPEs.

Comment: @Mark Peters where should i put the now1 and now2?

Comment: I agree with @MarkPeters, your initialization of the time variables will always give you just the difference in time it takes to create 2 Date objects and retrieve their times.So thats why the start time is both startTime and endTime.
Also we need more code/info to be able to help you with the rest, what do you mean by the database? Where are you inserting data into a db?

Comment: @Abu Why should use e.getActionCommand().equals("Log Out")? I don't think this is a problem. On your way, what would happen if e was null?

Comment: @R4j oops I didn't thought of e to be null thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following URL
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/
Use it at the begining of the app, and at the end.

If you are measuring the time looking how long the app executed, the above is not the best I guess. In case of that, try something like following

```
import java.util.*;

public class VectorTest
{
    Vector v = new Vector();

    public VectorTest()
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Get the start Time
        long endTime = 0;

       System.out.println( startTime);

       for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
       {
           v.add(i);
       }

        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(v.get(i));
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Get the end Time

        System.out.println(endTime);

        System.out.println("Difference in mili seconds: "+ (endTime-startTime)); //Print the difference in mili seconds
        System.out.println("Differencce in Seconds: "+ (endTime-startTime)/1000); // Print the difference in seconds

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new VectorTest();
    }
}
```

**EXTRA ADVISES FOR GOOD PROGRAMMING PRACTICES**

1. Look at the 3rd overloaded "CodeBase" constructor. You have 1 parameter in SQL query, but trying to set 2 in program, EVEN WITH invalid indexes 2 and 3
2. Close the connection inside the finally block
3. don't leave catch() method empty. Print the stack trace
4. Don't use the same PreparedStament everywhere. Crate them as local variables not as global ones. Sometimes there are delays in automated connection closing methods in databases. In such a case, your program will act in an unexpected way. If you declare them locally, the variables are gone as soon as the method is don e

Comment: what i want to do is to store the starting time at the startTime column in my database after clicking the button "log in" Then, when the user logs out, the time will be stored to endTime column in my database..

Comment: no problem. This will work. Or the links will work (based on your requirements. My example returns seconds, link gives examples for returning time in format dd:mm:yy). Find the start time as soon as the actionPerformed() method is called. Find the end time when the logout methods are called(at the end of the method).

Comment: *sigh* It's still the same. hmm.. what I did is I placed  dateFormatter.format(now1); before the LogIn validation and the dateFormatter.format(now1); after the LogOut validation.. what happens is, it display 4rows in my table in the database. :(

Comment: your question is about time, not about a database issue. I believe the suggestions here are more than enough for the time question. If there are any errors in inserting data to database, please open a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the times when the correct button is clicked instead of setting both start and end times for the same button. I would set a global variable for the startTime and calculate like so

```
private long startTime = null;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    LogicalChecker lc = new LogicalChecker();
    cobadatabase cb = new cobadatabase(studNumTF.getText());

    String output;


    //long secs = (now2.getTime() - now1.getTime()) / 1000;
    //long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60; 
    //long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60; 
    // long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;

    //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //long elapsedTime = finishTime - startTime; 

    long diff = (now2.getTime() - now1.getTime());
    cobadatabase cb2 = new cobadatabase(studNumTF.getText(),dateFormatter.format(now1),dateFormatter.format(now2),     diff);


    if("Log In".equals(e.getActionCommand())){    
         this.startTime = new Date().getTime(); // set start time
         ... do stuff
    } else if("Log Out".equals(e.getActionCommand())){   
         long totalTime =  new Date().getTime() - this.startTime(); // calculate total time
         ... do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion. but I think this code is not applicable to the class that I've made. if you would be very kind, please take a look at the classes that I have recently edited. What I want to do is to add the startTime and the endTime to 1 row only. I am really having a hard time doing this. I really need help.